# got a promotion but I am not happy!

Tags: productivity, title

I am a java web developer with 2 years experience in the web development. I got promoted last month to associate engineer but not really happy. currently I'm working on a new and important project with 2 talented engineers and a great architect BUT I had the feeling that I'm not good enough for that project coz of :

```
I am quite slow
not good enough in problem solving
sometimes I fell like I'm missing basics
sometimes I fell that my team members did not trust my work :/
```

as a conclusion, I think I'm still junior! and honestly, don't know is that's normal or I am having a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: misguided advice at Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257702/got-a-promotion-but-i-am-not-happy#comment521837_257702

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your point, Gnat

Comment: did you check [help/on-topic] prior to asking a question here? In particular, [this meta guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) it refers?

Comment: You are still junior with only two years experience no matter what title you have. If you feel that you need to up your game, then work on those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically, there are a couple of possibilities here to my mind noting that I'm not a mental health professional though I am a Software Developer that does have mental health issues:

1. Natural humility - In this case, one may have lofty standards and is trying to improve all the time. [Kaizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen) can be around the idea that one isn't good enough and thus one could always do better and be better. Some people may undervalue themselves as a way to keep expectations in check rather than have to stretch and force themselves to grow in a big way and step up.
2. Unhealthy perfectionism - ["The Perfectionist's Handbook"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470923369) would be a book about the idea of those people with unhealthy perfectionism where in expecting those standards to be met can cause some people to have anxiety or depression. In this case, there are various therapies like cognitive behavior therapy in extreme cases that may or may not apply for you. I do have generalized anxiety disorder and moderate depression so my view may differ from yours and I have done this work for 16 years now.

I'd likely be tempted to find a way to frame your concerns in a reasonable manner and check with your manager if you're doing OK in the role from management's perspective and what key areas would they want you to improve as perhaps they may think other things are where improvement would be better.

---

There are a couple of ways you could go about getting some feedback from your supervisor that depending on which way seems more natural here would be what you could consider:

1. Putting out ideas - In this case, you'd be telling your supervisor, "Hey, I was thinking about improving my skill with X by doing Y. What do you think about that idea?" The point here is to have a specific course of action that you are proposing so that you are taking care of something you see as an issue that your supervisor could say, "Yes, sounds good to me," or could give a longer answer to some extent.
2. External feedback - In this case, you're not giving a suggestion but rather want the feedback on, "How well do you think I'm doing here?" where if necessary you can say that, "I'd like to know from your perspective as my superior how well am I doing here," as the key is that you want to prevent any unmanaged expectations. If you need to explain further you could mention that you'd like to know the perspective of someone higher up in the organization about your performance. What is wanted here is just to know how are things going and be prepared that you may be asked, "How do you think you are doing?" which you answer and ask, "Do you agree with that perspective?" While you may want more than a "Yes/No" answer, there can be limits how much feedback your manager gives you that can be something to try to work on later.

Comment: first of all, Thanks for your answer 
secondly, I really like to ask my supervisors to give me feedback but I don't want to look like a guy with no self confident. what do think? there is a good way to ask them?